# Connect to invisible SMB Server by bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, samba, cifs

I want to run a bash script like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
read -p "username : " user_var
read -sp "password : " pass_var
echo
printf "//abcde.fghi.de/jklmn  /media/localfolder  cifs  domain=domainname username=$user_var , password=$pass_var , iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0" >> /etc/fstab
sudo mount -a
```

*//abcde.fghi.de/jklmn* and *domainname* are of course different.

For mount I get a reading error for the new line in fstab, but I can't figure out why.

In the GUI it works fine with the configuration:
[GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuU2h.png)

Comment: The options should be a comma-separated list without spaces ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely failing because the option string produced by your `printf` contains whitespace.

In any case, it's considered bad practice to include variable expansions directly inside a `printf` format string. Instead, use `%s` and move the variables outside as arguments:

```
printf '//abcde.fghi.de/jklmn /media/localfolder cifs domain=domainname,username=%s,password=%s,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0\n' "$user_var" "$pass_var"
```

Having said all that, I really question the idea of editing /etc/fstab on the fly like this - why not simply call `mount` with the relevant parameters?

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o domain=domainname,username="$user_var",password="$pass_var",iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm //abcde.fghi.de/jklmn  /media/localfolder
```

Comment: I've tried both and both fixed the problem with the reading error. But now unfortunately I get `mount error(2): No such file or directory`

Comment: That sounds like a different (unrelated) problem - does the mountpoint `/media/localfolder` exist? is the `cifs-utils` package installed?

Comment: yes installed and the mountpoint an the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

I did a mount like this recently and had to add `vers=1.0` to get it to work.

I have no idea really why or what the vers= parameter does, it worked for me and that was good enough! So it may be the same issue?

My complete line after `cifs` was this to enable the correct user/group id and read/write access: 
`username=???,password=???,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0  0`